# Need to make quarters of an year

Tags: r

I am using r to label a CSV column called month with abbreviation values such as jan,feb etc and all i want to do is label them into Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4.
Can any one help me?

I have tried commands like

```
forestfires$quarter <- factor(quarters(forestfires$month), 
                    labels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"))
```

Comment: try this method (as.yearqtr(strptime("26.03.2014", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))-
as.yearqtr(strptime("14.01.2013", format = "%d.%m.%Y")))*4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dat = data.frame(a=c("Jan","Apr","Oct")
monthlist = rep(c("Q1",'Q2','Q3','Q4'),each = 3)
names(monthlist) = month.abb
dat$quarters = monthlist[dat$a]
```